# Printing an ASCII Diamond: Bottom half broken?

Tags: java

I am attempting to print a diamond using a user inputted width of 7 that is supposed to look like this:

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
```

BUT, unfortunately my diamond is messed up on the bottom and it looks like this:

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
  *   *
    *
```

**Here's my code:**

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int width = 0;
    System.out.println("What is the width?");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    width = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Print top half of the diamond
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i += 2) {
        if (i == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (width / 2) + 1; j++)
                System.out.print(' ');
            System.out.print('*');
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < width - i; j += 2) {
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.print('*');
            for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.print('\n');
    }
    //Print bottom half of the diamond
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i+=2) {
        if (i == 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (width / 2) + 1; j++)
                System.out.print(' ');
            System.out.print('*');
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i + 2; j += 2) {
                System.out.print(' ');
            } System.out.print ('*');
            for (int j = 0; j < (width / 2) - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(' ');
            } System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.print('\n');
    }
}
```

I am not totally sure how to fix the bottom part of it, that is what I have been trying to figure out! These nested for loops are tricky

Comment: Trying to simplify your logic first, you only print out two lines for the bottom part as the out-most loop only executed twice for i = 0 and i = 2. Hope that helps.

Comment: @christopher_miller Why does the bottom half of the diamond have hardcoded values?  The top half has `for (... ; foo < width)` whereas the bottom half has `for (... ; foo < 3)`.  Also, your top half increments from zero to width, I would assume the bottom half would decrement from width to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple fix, change bottom loop variable `i` from `3` to `5`, and line after that `i` from `2` to `4`.

```
//Print bottom half of the diamond
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i+=2) {
    if (i == 4) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (width / 2) + 1; j++)
            System.out.print(' ');
        System.out.print('*');
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i + 2; j += 2) {
            System.out.print(' ');
        } System.out.print ('*');
        for (int j = 0; j < (width / 2) - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(' ');
        } System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.print('\n');
}
```

Comment: I am unsure which you are talking about changing to 5 and 4

Comment: @ChristopherMiller, please note that the bottom half loop control variable `i` shouldn't be hard-coded at all. Change to `5` will working for input of `width` `7`, but not other values. You need change your bottom half loop control on `width` rather than any hard-coded value. `width - 2` to start with maybe, then the code to print single `*` will need change as well. Sorry can't help much for now as I am on Chromebook with my Mobile data :(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 3 in bottom half for loop to 4. It seems as you lack one row. That might do it. Can't promise I'm new here and just trying to help! :)

Comment: No dice :( It's throwing me for a loop, literally

Comment: Shoot. Then I don't know. Too bad :/ Hope someone who's more experienced can help. Best of luck though